# Chamar função Java (Android) dentro de uma aplicação mobile híbrida com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html5, bluetooth

Estamos construindo uma aplicação web híbrida, que necessita imprimir em uma impressora portátil por *bluetooth*. Porém a impressora é importada e só vem com um SDK em Java, que não é o nosso forte!

Precisávamos imprimir a partir do código JavaScript, mas não sei se consigo chamar as funções Java de impressão ou algo parecido. E a outra alternativa seria criar um *plugin*, no qual já estamos trabalhando mas vai demorar muito.

É um projeto mobile, será criado um `.apk` e é totalmente *off-line*.

Comment: O que é possível fazer: Fazer uma função em javascript, que faça uma requisição ajax, que execute uma função em java (dentro do java), e no javascript, capturar o evento, dados, etc... desta execução (dentro do java). [aqui tem uma explicação](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart_pt_BR.html)

Comment: Já tentou este plugin? https://github.com/eddysby2000/Cordova-Bluetooth-Printer-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Não há forma direta de se fazer isso porque o javascript não vai ter uma API disponível no navegador capaz de falar diretamente com a JDK.

Entretanto, o javascript pode facilmente fazer requisições via Ajax, que usa HTTP. Então você cria uma aplicação em Java, que disponibiliza uma API REST e a publica em algum IP:porta qualquer. A aplicação javascript se comunica com a aplicação java usando REST. A aplicação java, por sua vez, se preocupa em falar com a impressora.

Comment: No nosso caso, a aplicação sera usada em um aparelho com android, totalmente off-line, para emissão de tickets, e compilada em um .apk. Consigo montar esta estrutura mesmo assim?

Comment: @Rodrigo Como sua aplicação é um APK em Android e não no navegador e é totalmente off-line, a coisa muda totalmente de figura (e minha resposta acaba sendo inválida). Neste caso, não sei qual seria a resposta, mas tenho quase certeza de que ela existe e não é muito difícil. Basicamente, o seu problema se reduz a implementar um APK em Android onde parte do código é em java e parte em javascript.

Comment: Imagino isto mesmo @Victor, a questão é como, pelo menos o caminho!

Comment: offline, você pode criar um pequeno banco de dados com um `arquivo.json`, pode usar jquery com o método `$.load( 'arquivo.json', function(data){  ...  })`; nem precisa de java para isso, pode apenas por nome aos bois, para os arquivos...

Comment: Ou para sofrer menos, use o [ionic](http://ionicframework.com)